# Enable submit button according to the response of the recaptcha user Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, recaptcha

My goal is that a form button is enabled, if the user correctly responded to the recaptcha, I already found a solution using pure javascript ([stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018213/recaptcha-2-0-enable-submit-button-on-callback-if-recaptcha-successful)), but I need to do it with VueJs, when using the data-callback attribute of recaptcha, it indicates an error, the which says: "ReCAPTCHA could not find user-provided function: responseRC ()", with which I can not get the answer and activate the button.

My code
- HTML

```
<div id='app'>
  <label for="name">
    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="namex">
  </label>
  <label for="agree">
    <input id="agree" type="checkbox" value="agree" />I Agree</lable>
  <p>
    <hr>
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld8BDUU0000Edp4MdRqV24fKJe8llSzLfiEQEH" data-callback="responseRC()" ></div>
  <hr>
  <button :name="buttonX" disabled>Button</button>
</div>
```

Code Vue JS

```
var ins = new Vue({
      el : '#app',
      data: {
        //checked : false,
        namex: 'Javier',
        buttonX: ''
      },
      mounted: function() {
        this.buttonX.disabled;
        console.log('monta algo');

      },
      beforeupdated: function(){
        console.log('cambia algo');
        this.buttonX.disabled.false;
      },

      methods: {
        disableButton: function(){
            this.buttonX.disabled=false;
        },
        responseRC: function(){
            console.log("The captcha has been already solved");
            if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0){
               console.log("The captcha has been already solved");
            }
        }

      }
    });
```

Comment: Try changing `data-callback` value to `ins.responseRC()`, so the reCaptcha script can correctly find and call the function (which is inside `ins`, instead of at global scope). Also, shouldn't the function name be passed without the `()`, as specified in the answer you linked?

Comment: hello, thanks for the help, but I changed `data-callback = "ins.responseRC"` and the error continues `ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: ins.responseRC `

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, you have to use `@verify`, inside the method it'll refer to toggle the `boolean` flag and include this in the `:disabled` of a `button`.

The logic I got (`Vuetify`/`Class API`/`TypeScript` syntax):

**in html** (the `ref` you might skip, I'm using this to [reset reCAPTCHA on reset button click](https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha/issues/530#issuecomment-699818085))

```
<vue-recaptcha
  @verify="recaptchaVerified"
  ref="recaptcha"
  sitekey="ABC..."
></vue-recaptcha>
```

**:disabled on a button** (note the `isRecaptchaValid` flag)

```
<v-btn
  :disabled="!isFormValid || !isRecaptchaValid"
  text
  color="purple darken-2"
  type="submit"
  >Send</v-btn
>
```

**TypeScript logic**

```
public isRecaptchaValid: boolean = false;
public recaptchaVerified(response: any): void {
  this.isRecaptchaValid = true;
}
```